# woocommerce как получить данные не зарегистрированного клиента при оформлении заказа?

Tags: woocommerce

как получить данные не зарегистрированного клиента при создании заказа и на какой хук повесить отправку этих данных?
при оформлении заказа создается клиент, заказ оформляется без регистрации на сайте

Comment: наивное недоумение: если пользователь не зарегистрирован, то о каких «данных» может быть вообще речь? думаю, стоит это уточнить прямо в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit].

Comment: чтобы совершить заказ не нужно регистрироваться на сайте, при оформлении заказа создается клиент не пользователь, вот его данные нужно получить

Comment: Речь о том, чтобы уточнить о каких конкретно данных идет речь. Так-то по-умолчанию Вы уже получаете определенные данные в форме оформления заказа, когда пользователь ее заполни, верно?

Comment: да именно эти данные мне и нужно получить, телефон, емаил, имя, id клиента, комментарий, дата создания клиента
как я думаю - нужно повесится на хук создания клиента и получить эти данный для дальнейшей отправки, но у меня ничего не получается(
пробовал - woocommerce_created_customer

Comment: частично получаю данные с помощью - woocommerce_new_order
только вот так
    `$name = $order1->get_billing_first_name();
    $phone = $order1->get_billing_phone();
    $email = $order1->get_billing_email();
    $description = $order1->get_customer_note();`
`$id = $order1->get_customer_id();` - возвращает 0, не понимаю как его получить

Comment: нашел такое решение, может кому-то будет полезно
[https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/function/DataStore::get_guest_id_by_email]
правда гостевой клиент создается не сразу, а через какое-то время, у меня это секунд 20, тоже надо учесть